# how do I make a portable isnan/isinf function

Tags: c++, c, math, function

I've been using `isinf`, `isnan` functions on Linux platforms which worked perfectly.
But this didn't work on OS-X, so I decided to use `std::isinf` `std::isnan` which works on both Linux and OS-X.

But the Intel compiler doesn't recognize it, and I guess its a bug in the intel compiler according to http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/showthread.php?t=64188

So now I just want to avoid the hassle and define my own `isinf`, `isnan` implementation.

Does anyone know how this could be done?

edit:

I ended up doing this in my source code for making `isinf`/`isnan` working

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

#ifdef __INTEL_COMPILER
#include <mathimf.h>
#endif

int isnan_local(double x) { 
#ifdef __INTEL_COMPILER
  return isnan(x);
#else
  return std::isnan(x);
#endif
}

int isinf_local(double x) { 
#ifdef __INTEL_COMPILER
  return isinf(x);
#else
  return std::isinf(x);
#endif
}


int myChk(double a){
  std::cerr<<"val is: "<<a <<"\t";
  if(isnan_local(a))
    std::cerr<<"program says isnan";
  if(isinf_local(a))
    std::cerr<<"program says isinf";
  std::cerr<<"\n";
  return 0;
}

int main(){
  double a = 0;
  myChk(a);
  myChk(log(a));
  myChk(-log(a));
  myChk(0/log(a));
  myChk(log(a)/log(a));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Closely related: [__Checking if a double (or float) is nan in C++__](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570669/checking-if-a-double-or-float-is-nan-in-c)

Answer (score 25):

You could also use boost for this task:

```
#include <boost/math/special_functions/fpclassify.hpp> // isnan

if( boost::math::isnan( ... ) .... )
```

Comment: Yes, bring ~7000 header files to bear on a problem that can be solved with 2 or 3 lines.

Comment: YOU don't have to use it, but if someone nevertheless uses boost anyway, this is a quite PORTABLE and SHORT solution. Without #IFDEFs around, heh?

Comment: The OP's question is "how do I MAKE a portable isnan/isinf function". It's crystal clear that the OP wants to implement it himself. This answer should be posted as a comment, not an answer. It doesn't answer the question, even worse it recommends to use a huge library.

Comment: Luckily Boost is open source, so he also may read the implementations to get a guess how this can be solved. As the OP mentions that he has used before predefined isnan isinf  functions, he probably does not need to reinvent the wheel. If the size of the lib is really an issue here, which you are ASSUMING!, than other solutions posted here, or Boost, may be helpful. Unless he doesn't make the size an requirement, it is safe to DON'T OPTIMIZE FIRST!. BTW the bug he mentions has been fixed meanwhile.

Answer (score 23):

I've not tried this, but I would think

```
int isnan(double x) { return x != x; }
int isinf(double x) { return !isnan(x) && isnan(x - x); }
```

would work. It feels like there should be a better way for isinf, but that should work.

Comment: I've done something like your isnan function and it work on Windows, Linux, and OS X.

Comment: This (x != x) will not work in MSVC or gcc with the fast math flag (i.e. if the floating point implementation does not conform to IEEE). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7s85ffb.aspx

Comment: Also `int isinf(double x) { return fabs(x) > DBL_MAX; }`.

Comment: `-ffast-math` breaks this, use `std::isnan`.

Answer (score 18):

According to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985#Representation_of_non-numbers), **infinity** is easy to check:

- sign = either 0 or 1 bit indicating positive/negative infinity.
- exponent = all 1 bits.
- mantissa = all 0 bits.

**NaN** is a bit more complicated because it doesn't have a unique representation:

- sign = either 0 or 1.
- exponent = all 1 bits.
- mantissa = anything except all 0 bits (since all 0 bits represents infinity).

Below is the code for double-precision floating-point case. Single-precision can be similarly written (recall that the exponent is 11-bits for doubles and 8-bits for singles):

```
int isinf(double x)
{
    union { uint64 u; double f; } ieee754;
    ieee754.f = x;
    return ( (unsigned)(ieee754.u >> 32) & 0x7fffffff ) == 0x7ff00000 &&
           ( (unsigned)ieee754.u == 0 );
}

int isnan(double x)
{
    union { uint64 u; double f; } ieee754;
    ieee754.f = x;
    return ( (unsigned)(ieee754.u >> 32) & 0x7fffffff ) +
           ( (unsigned)ieee754.u != 0 ) > 0x7ff00000;
}
```

The implementation is pretty straightforward (I took those from the [OpenCV header files](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/cvdef.h#L423)). It uses a union over an equal-sized unsigned 64-bit integer which you might need to correctly declare:

```
#if defined _MSC_VER
  typedef unsigned __int64 uint64;
#else
  typedef uint64_t uint64;
#endif
```

Comment: if anyone is interested, that definition in OpenCV moved around, and it's now in the `hal` module. Here's a more permanent link: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/3.0.0/modules/hal/include/opencv2/hal/defs.h#L447

Comment: +1 This clearly seems to be the most platform-independent approach that is guaranteed to get the correct answer without the need of including libraries and without regard to compiler settings.

Comment: I've heard that plonking a value of one type into a union and reading it back as a different type is undefined behavior in C++ (or maybe just C?). Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @NikoO I'm not sure either, a quick search turned the following results: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52290456, https://stackoverflow.com/q/25664848, https://stackoverflow.com/q/11373203, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning#Use_of_union. An alternative that also seems accepted is using `memcpy` : https://stackoverflow.com/q/17789928, https://stackoverflow.com/q/51300626, or using C++20 `std::bit_cast`

Answer (score 8):

This works under Visual Studio 2008:

```
#include <math.h>
#define isnan(x) _isnan(x)
#define isinf(x) (!_finite(x))
#define fpu_error(x) (isinf(x) || isnan(x))
```

For safety, I recommend using fpu_error(). I believe some numbers are picked up with isnan(), and some with isinf(), and you need both to be safe.

Here is some test code:

```
double zero=0;
double infinite=1/zero;
double proper_number=4;
printf("isinf(infinite)=%d.\n",isinf(infinite));
printf("isinf(proper_number)=%d.\n",isinf(proper_number));
printf("isnan(infinite)=%d.\n",isnan(infinite));
printf("isnan(proper_number)=%d.\n",isnan(proper_number));

double num=-4;
double neg_square_root=sqrt(num);
printf("isinf(neg_square_root)=%d.\n",isinf(neg_square_root));
printf("isinf(proper_number)=%d.\n",isinf(proper_number));
printf("isnan(neg_square_root)=%d.\n",isnan(neg_square_root));
printf("isnan(proper_number)=%d.\n",isnan(proper_number));
```

Here is the output:

```
isinf(infinite)=1.
isinf(proper_number)=0.
isnan(infinite)=0.
isnan(proper_number)=0.
isinf(neg_square_root)=1.
isinf(proper_number)=0.
isnan(neg_square_root)=1.
isnan(proper_number)=0.
```

Comment: _finite returns false for both inf *and* nan, so your isinf implementation is incorrect - in fact, your own demo output shows that :-)

Answer (score 7):

`isnan` is part of C++11 now, included in GCC++ I believe, and Apple LLVM.

Now [MSVC++ has an `_isnan` function in `<float.h>`.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzthab44.aspx)

Appropriate `#define`s and `#include`s should make a suitable workaround.

However, I recommend [preventing nan from ever occurring, instead of nan detection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18283170/111307).

Comment: Sometimes you can't control if there are nans in your data, especially if you didn't originate the data, and the output still needs to be aware of those nans.

Comment: Sometimes you use NaN to indicate "invalid", similar to null_ptr.

Answer (score 6):

Well, ideally, you'd wait until Intel fixes the bug or provides a workaround :-)

But if you want to detect `NaN` and `Inf` from IEEE754 values, map it to an integer (32 or 64 bit depending on whether it's single or double precision) and check if the exponent bits are all 1. This indicates those two cases.

You can distinguish between `NaN` and `Inf` by checking the high order bit of the mantissa. If it's 1, that's `NaN` otherwise `Inf`.

`+/-Inf` is dictated by the sign bit.

For single precision (32-bit values), the sign is the high-order bit (b31), exponent is the next eight bits (plus a 23-bit mantissa). For double precision, the sign is still the high-order bit but the exponent is eleven bits (plus 52 bits for the mantissa).

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) has all the gory details.

The following code shows you how the encoding works.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void decode (char *s, double x) {
    long y = *(((long*)(&x))+1);

    printf("%08x ",y);
    if ((y & 0x7ff80000L) == 0x7ff80000L) {
        printf ("NaN  (%s)\n", s);
        return;
    }
    if ((y & 0xfff10000L) == 0x7ff00000L) {
        printf ("+Inf (%s)\n", s);
        return;
    }
    if ((y & 0xfff10000L) == 0xfff00000L) {
        printf ("-Inf (%s)\n", s);
        return;
    }
    printf ("%e (%s)\n", x, s);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    double dvar;

    printf ("sizeof double = %d\n", sizeof(double));
    printf ("sizeof long   = %d\n", sizeof(long));

    dvar = 1.79e308; dvar = dvar * 10000;
    decode ("too big", dvar);

    dvar = -1.79e308; dvar = dvar * 10000;
    decode ("too big and negative", dvar);

    dvar = -1.0; dvar = sqrt(dvar);
    decode ("imaginary", dvar);

    dvar = -1.79e308;
    decode ("normal", dvar);

    return 0;
}
```

and it outputs:

```
sizeof double = 8
sizeof long   = 4
7ff00000 +Inf (too big)
fff00000 -Inf (too big and negative)
fff80000 NaN  (imaginary)
ffefdcf1 -1.790000e+308 (normal)
```

Just keep in mind that this code (but not the method) depends a great deal on the sizes of your longs which is not overly portable. But, if you have to bit-fiddle to get the information, you've already entered that territory :-)

As an aside, I've always found [Harald Schmidt's IEEE754 converter](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatApplet/IEEE754.html) very useful for floating point analysis.

Comment: Unfortunately, the expression `*(((long*)(&x))+1)` invokes undefined behaviour: After the cast of the pointer to `long*`, the compiler is allowed to infer that the resulting pointer is not aliased with the original one, because one points to a `long` while the other points to a `double`, and perform optimizations on it. This might become a problem when the compiler decides to inline `decode()`, since it would allow the compiler to move the integer read in front of the floating point write, which obviously would produce garbage. To be safe, use `memcpy()` instead of a cast.

Answer (score 3):

Just use that super simple IEEE 754-1985-compliant code:

```
static inline bool  ISINFINITE( float a )           { return (((U32&) a) & 0x7FFFFFFFU) == 0x7F800000U; }
static inline bool  ISINFINITEPOSITIVE( float a )   { return (((U32&) a) & 0xFFFFFFFFU) == 0x7F800000U; }
static inline bool  ISINFINITENEGATIVE( float a )   { return (((U32&) a) & 0xFFFFFFFFU) == 0xFF800000U; }
static inline bool  ISNAN( float a )                { return !ISINFINITE( a ) && (((U32&) a) & 0x7F800000U) == 0x7F800000U; }
static inline bool  ISVALID( float a )              { return (((U32&) a) & 0x7F800000U) != 0x7F800000U; }
```

Answer (score 2):

As brubelsabs said Boost offers this feature but, as reported [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/utils/fpclass.html), instead of using

```
if (boost::math::isnan(number))
```

This should be used:

```
if ((boost::math::isnan)(number))
```

Answer (score 1):

No-one seems to have mentioned the C99 function fpclassify which returns:

One of FP_INFINITE, FP_NAN, FP_NORMAL, FP_SUBNORMAL, FP_ZERO or implementation-defined type, specifying the category of arg.

This works with visual studio, but I don't know about OS-X.

Answer (score 0):

The following article has some interesting tricks for isnan and isinf:
http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/983

Answer (score -3):

this works on osx

```
#include <math.h>
```

also this might be portable,

```
int isinf( double x ) { return x == x - 1; }
```

edit:

as Chris pointed out the above may fail with large x

```
int isinf( double x ) { return x == x * 2; }
```

Comment: Can't this give you the wrong answer sometimes? If x is sufficiently large, it doesn't record the number with integer precision. (i.e. 1.2345*2^100 - 1 == 1.2345*2^100, but 1.2345*2^100 != infinity)

Comment: Oops, after int isinf( double x ) { return x == x * 2; } edition, you now have isinf(0.0)...

Comment: What if `x * 2` overflows?