# using an if statement to switch nan values in an array to 0.0?

Tags: c, floating-point, nan

I am doing some calculations with points and the vectors between the points and it is no surprise to me that I get nan for when the points are very close together. What I am trying to do now is rid all the nan values in the array that I have stored in an array along with the good data. I am hoping to just use a bit of code like so:

```
   if( angle[i] == nan ) { angle[i] = 0.0 };
```

at least that is what I have tried and I get errors when I try that. Does any one know how to get rid of nan values and replace them with just a 0.0?

Comment: Revise your tags to get better answers.

Comment: What language are you using?
What errors do you get?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I remember, in every language, NaN will compare false to everything, including itself.  You can use this behavior to weed it out:

```
if( angle[i] != angle[i] ) { angle[i] = 0.0 };
```

This looks like C, C++, or Java; in all of these, this trick should work.

Comment: that did the trick. I read about how it always returns false but did not think of trying that.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming this is C then use [isnan](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isnan) from `<math.h>`:

```
#include <math.h>

if (isnan(angle[i]))
{
    angle[i] = 0.0;
}
```

Comment: I did not try your method but I am sure it would work as well, I came across that method a few times when I was looking for a solution to this myself but was unsure how to implement it.

Comment: `x!=x` is usually a faster way to check for nan than `isnan(x)`. The latter is only useful in that it avoids raising floating point exception flags, but if you don't care about/don't use floating point exception flags, `x!=x` is better.

Comment: isnan for c99, _isnan for visual c

Comment: Relevant: [how do I make a portable isnan/isinf function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249110/how-do-i-make-a-portable-isnan-isinf-function)