# filtering out -inf and inf values to 0 in c++

Tags: c++

lets say you have a `std::complex<double> array[N];`

how would you set all `-inf` and `inf` values to 0 in a for loop?

`std::isinf`  won't work for me the compiler predates C++11

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249110/how-do-i-make-a-portable-isnan-isinf-function

Comment: @robert thank's i'll try the solutions there but i'm not sure they will work with std::complex , maybe if i just use the real part of the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::replace( array, array + N, std::complex( std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity(), 0.0), std::complex(0.0) );
std::replace( array, array + N, std::complex( -std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity(), 0.0), std::complex(0.0) );
```

or

```
bool isinf( std::complex<double> d )
{
  return std::abs( d.real() ) == std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity()
}

std::replace_if( array, array + N, isinf, 0.0 );
```

Comment: the first doesn't work as is and the seconds doesn't work either, its `std::complex<double>`  not `vector<double>` or just `double`

Comment: @pyCthon what infinity are you referring to in your question?  Are you looking for `std::complex( inf, 0 )`?

Comment: @pyCthon Edited, based on what I think you're asking.

Comment: @pyCthon Are you certain that you're dealing with values like `std::complex(inf, -inf)`?  An "imaginary negative infinity" does have a meaning, but it's a very unusual thing to come across.

Comment: characteristic function before use in FFT because -inf or inf gives me errors , and my matlab equivalent code doesn't have an inf or -inf in it , the real part is the same thou

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity()` will provide a value that tells you whether a number is an infinity or not.

Here is an example code for a `vector` of `double` values; you can change the `repl_inf` to use `complex<double>` instead.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int repl_inf (double v) { return (v== std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity() || -v== std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity()) ? 0.0 : v; }

int main() {
    vector<double> v;
    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(1.0/0.0);
    v.push_back(2);
    v.push_back(-1.0/0.0);
    transform (v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin(), repl_inf);
    for (int i = 0 ; i != v.size() ; i++) {
        cout << v[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

On ideone: [link](http://ideone.com/XkAFV).

For `complex<double>`:

```
bool isInf(double v) {
    return v== std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity()
       || -v== std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
}
bool isInf(complex<double> c) {
    return isInf(c.real) || isInf(c.imag);
}
```

Comment: This needs a negative infinity test.

Comment: it's not working for me... i tried `for ( int i = 0; i< N; i++){
     if  (real(phi[i])== std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity() || -real(phi[i])== std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity()){
       phi[i] = 0;
     }` 

where phi is std::complex<double> , failed with out the real() as well still printed out inf and -inf

Comment: @pyCthon You need to define a function that tests individual components of `complex` for infinity. I edited the answer to show how it can be done.