# Where is isnan() in MSVC 2010?

Tags: c++, std

I'm trying to write a program which uses `std::isnan()` with MSVC 2010. I include `cmath` but unfortunately the compiler returns the error:

> isnan is not part of the std namespace

Does MSVC 2010 support this function from std (AKA C++11)?

Comment: MSVC 2010 is not very C++11 complaint.  Their most compliant version is 2015.

Comment: @NathanOliver, unfortunately at the moment I'm stuck with 2010. Any hint on the fix?

Comment: @BatCoder, nothing to post. I just wrote `if( std::isnan( x ) )` and got aforementioned error.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249110/how-do-i-make-a-portable-isnan-isinf-function) may help.  Can you use boost?

Comment: How about `x != x`?

Comment: It was not standard in 2010, so it is called [`_isnan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzthab44(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: @Igor To add an explanation to the solution `x != x`: if a float is NaN, then it always compares false to an equality comparison, even if compared to NaN. Since a float `x` usually always compares equal to itself, if `x == x` is false, then `x` must be NaN.
But you probably should use `_isnan`

Comment: [VS2010 to present C++ Standard support matrix](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx). Basically which versions of VS support what portions of what standards.

Comment: To add to what @BoPersson said, `_isnan()` is defined in `<float.h>`, and by extension in `<cfloat>`.

Comment: I would also recommend looking out for other "gotchas" in VS 2010's implementation of C++0x, such as `char16_t` and `char32_t`; in VS 2010, they're actually defined as `typedef unsigned short char16_t;` and `typedef unsigned int char32_t;`.  In general, VS 2010 can _handle_ most C++11 code (notable exceptions being uniform initialisation & variadic templates), but it isn't actually _compliant_ with as much of C++11 as you would expect, and uses some wonky hacks to mimic some of the features it doesn't actually support yet to keep valid code from breaking.

Answer (score 5):

`std::isnan` *is* in `<cmath>` : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isnan

Your problem is probably VS2010 which has very poor C++11 support. I'd recommend grabbing VS2015 which is *much* better in that regard.

As can be seen [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzthab44(v=vs.100).aspx) VS2010 only has `_isnan` .

Comment: as I wrote above, for now I'm stuck with 2010. Any hint on the fix?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. That isnan is in c++11 according to your link says nothing about msvc2010 having it.

Comment: Edited my answer to add a link to a page showing VS2010 only has _isnan.   Btw; this stuff is highly googlable.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, Visual Studio's C++11 support hasn't been that [complete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0ybw9fy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) until the [2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0ybw9fy%28v=vs.140%29.aspx) version, so you won't be able to utilize the C++ [`std::isnan`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isnan) functionality. Interestingly, there is a C99 [`isnan`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/isnan) macro, but it's implementation defined and VS 2010 does not seem to have any of those macros. Fortunately though, the MS line of compilers do have their MS specific `_` versions of the [`_isnan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzthab44.aspx) functionality. So you could write your own `isnan` as such:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cfloat>
#include <limits>

namespace non_std
{

    template < typename T >
    bool isnan(T val)
    {
        #if defined(_WIN64)
            // x64 version
            return _isnanf(val) != 0;
        #else
            return _isnan(val) != 0;
        #endif
    }

}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    float value = 1.0f;
    std::cout << value << " is " <<
        (non_std::isnan(value) ? "NaN" : "NOT NaN") << std::endl;

    if (std::numeric_limits<float>::has_quiet_NaN) {
        value = std::numeric_limits<float>::quiet_NaN();
        std::cout << value << " is " <<
            (non_std::isnan(value) ? "NaN" : "NOT NaN") << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

On my machine this produces the output:

> 1 is NOT NaN
>
> 1.#QNAN is NaN

Note that the `_isnanf` is for 64-bit applications and the `_WIN64` macro might not necessarily be defined, so if you target 64 bit be sure to adjust that.

Hope that can help.