# Scala's Option or Rust's Result error handling in C

Tags: c, scala, error-handling, rust

I started writing C again after professionally doing Scala and Python for quite some time.
After using Scala's "Option" and "Either" error handling patterns and recently tasted the Rust way I wanted something similar in C. So I came up with something like this:

```c
typedef struct {
    int age;
    char* name;
} User;

typedef struct {
    char* error;
    User* value;
} UserResult;

UserResult get_user() {
    /* Some complicated user fetching process .. that fails */
    return (UserResult) { .error = "403 Unauthorized\n" };
}

int main(void) {
    UserResult res = get_user();
    if (res.error)
        handle_error(res.error);
    if (res.value)
        do_something(res.value);
    /* ... */
    return 0;
}
```

But this isn't really safe (we could access invalid pointers). How can I get something similar than the Scala or Rust way of handling errors in C ?

EDIT: corrected UserResult field name "value"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many ways to handle errors in existing C code in the wild. So many that it represents a non neglectable mental load to understand how to handle errors for various libraries, even more so when using several at the same time in a project.

Introducing a new way of handling errors could be beneficial, but on the flip side, it could be akin to [this famous XKCD comic](https://xkcd.com/927/).

The Rust (and Scala, etc) way is indeed very powerful and has a few advantages over other older idioms.

However, the Result idiom is based on [Sum Types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union), which are not natively supported by the C language.
There is no guarantee that your `UserResult` is in a coherent state. `user` and `error` could be both null, or non-null.

This could be modified a bit, for example by using a union instead:

```
typedef struct{
    union {
        char* error;
        User user;
    }
    bool has_error;
} UserResult;
```

The `has_error` flag indicates which field is actually filled:

```
int main(void) {
    UserResult res = get_user();
    if (res.has_error)
        handle_error(res.error);
    else
        do_something(res.value);
    /* ... */
    return 0;
}
```

This is not perfect, as the C language does not enforce proper union access, instead invoking [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52290456/is-the-following-c-union-access-pattern-undefined-behavior) when used incorrectly.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is even with `UserResult` model in C the onus is still on the programmer to remember to do null-checks, that is, compiler is not enforcing it, so even though we declared `UserResult` nothing prevents us to mistakenly write

```
int main(void) {
  UserResult res = get_user();
  do_something(res.value); // Runtime error: oops I forgot to null-check and unfortunately compiler is still happy
  return 0;
}
```

whilst with Scala's `Option` programmer is forced by the compiler to deal with the situation, for example,

```
case class User(age: Int, name: String)
case class UserResult(value: Option[User], error: Option[String])

def get_user(): UserResult = {
  /* Some complicated user fetching process .. that fails */
  UserResult(value = None, error = Some("403 Unauthorized"))
}

def do_something(user: User) = ???

object Main extends App {
  val res = get_user()
  do_something(res.value) // Compile-time error: oops I forgot to "null-check" but fortunately the compiler is unhappy
}
```