# Testing if Float value is NaN

Tags: c, floating-point, solaris, nan

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Checking if a double (or float) is `nan` in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570669/checking-if-a-double-or-float-is-nan-in-c)

I have a requirement to check if float is `NaN`. By going through some of the links I found the most common check.

```
FLOAT32 f32_test_NaN = (some_value);
if (f32_test_NaN == f32_test_NaN)
{
    //do something;
}
else
{
    // do something;
}
```

But this does not seem to work for me. My code is as follows:

```
FLOAT32 test_NaN = 0x414570A3;//some value - is this ok?
```

Debugging on GDB:

```
(gdb) p test_NaN
$1 = 1.09506982e+09

(gdb) p/x test_NaN
$2 = 0x41457080 // Hex is not same as init value - What is compiler doing?
```

So in my case `test_NaN` is equal to `test_NaN`.

Please let me know if any compiler setting has to be done. I am running on solaris. Or is there any other way to check the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570669/checking-if-a-double-or-float-is-nan-in-c

Comment: Why not using `isnan()` from math.h? Any specially reason?

Comment: That standard function is not available in the environment.

Comment: Not a dupe - this is about C, not C++

Comment: The title is probably misleading - it is about a supposedly  `nan` not being a `nan` after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is maybe in your initialization (at least that explains the value you see in gdb) :

```
FLOAT32 test_NaN = 0x414570A3;
```

The hex value given is considered as an integer and converted to float (with exponent and value) meaning it is stored in a different format.

If you want to force the bits inside the float, then you need to memcpy:

```
FLOAT32 test_NaN;
memcpy(&test_NaN, 0x414570A3, 4);
```

Comment: Cool!! I knew problem was there. But memcpy crashed for me though. Hence is just did this and it worked!! UINT32 test_NaN[2] = {0xffffffff,0xfffffff7}; FLOAT32 test = *( FLOAT32* )test_NaN;(not showing pointers in comments (?!?))

Comment: Your code is incorrect. memcpy must copy from address. So store 0x414570A3 in an int variable first.

Answer (score 23):

Include `math.h` and use `int isnan(x)`. Don't forget to link with `-lm`

Comment: Perhaps one should add that this "only" appeared in C99, so not all compilers might implement this, yet.

Comment: suncc supports it, which seems to be what the questioner is using.

Comment: Actually `isnan` isn't a function, at least when you use it after including `math.h`: it's a macro with implementation-defined definition.

Answer (score 11):

If `<math.h>` is not available, then do this:

```
if (x != x)
{
    // x is NaN
}
```

Comment: Thanks, its the same I am doing, but probably I am not initializing correctly. Can you tell me what value I can initialize 'x' with to test for NaN?

Comment: @kp11 Any floating point expression should do.

Answer (score 7):

if (x != x)

For x = 0x7FBFFFFF (sign bit 0, a = 0, rest of bits 1)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN

> A bit-wise example of a IEEE floating-point standard single precision (32-bit) NaN: s111 1111 1axx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx where s is the sign, x is the payload, and a determines the type of NaN. If a = 1, it is a quiet NaN; if a is zero and the payload is nonzero, then it is a signaling NaN