# What's the portable/correct/standard way to test `NaN` in C++?

Tags: c++, testing, nan

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Checking if a double (or float) is nan in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570669/checking-if-a-double-or-float-is-nan-in-c)

How should I do to test NaN in C++ in portable/correct/standard manner?