# How to check for undefined value of a double?

Tags: c++, undefined

I am trying to figure out a way to check for a undefined value of a slope in which case it would be vertical. I have tried using `NULL` but that doesn't seem to work.

```
double Point::Slope(Point &p2)
{
   double slop = 0;
   slop = (y - p2.y) / (x - p2.x);

   if (slop == NULL)
   {
      slop = 10e100;
   }

   return slop;   
}
```

Comment: You need to review your questions and accept some answers!

Comment: This would help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570669/checking-if-a-double-or-float-is-nan-in-c/570694#570694

Comment: You need to define what would be outside the range of acceptable values and then check for that.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the indicated question.  See this conversation on meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109993/guidelines-for-closing-questions-as-exact-duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean nan ('not a number') with "undefined", you should avoid computing one in the first place, i.e. by checking that the denominator of a '/' operation is not zero. Second, you can always check for nan by

```
#include <cmath>
bool std::isnan(x);   // since C++11
bool isnan(x);        // pre C++11, from the C math library, defined as macro
```

see the man pages, or [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isnan).

Comment: `isnan` is not a Standard function, AFAICT.

Comment: @JohnDibling It is since C++11.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, NULL == 0. This is not what you seek.

Maybe this may help you : http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Infinity-and-NaN.html

Try the isnan(float) function.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend avoiding the divide-by-zero all together (by the way... why don't you call it `slope` instead of `slop`?):

```
double Point::Slope(Point&p2)
{
    double slope = 0;
    double xDelta = x - p2.x;
    double yDelta = y - p2.y;

    if (xDelta != 0)
    {
        slope = yDelta / xDelta;
    }

    return slope;   
}
```