# isnan strange error

Tags: eclipse-cdt, nan

I'm getting a lot of headache with a simple `isnan` test in my code. I have a 3d vector class with variables `x`,`y`,`z` of type `double`, and the following function in the header file:

```
#ifdef WIN32
bool IsValid() const {return !_isnan(x) && _finite(x) && !_isnan(y) && _finite(y) && !_isnan(z) && _finite(z);} //is a valid vector? (funky windows _ versions...) 
#else
bool IsValid() const {return !isnan(x) && finite(x) && !isnan(y) && finite(y) && !isnan(z) && finite(z);} //is a valid vector? 
#endif
```

I'm building in a Linux GCC environment on Eclipse CDT and getting the following error:

```
Function '__isnanl' could not be resolved
```

as well as

```
Function '__isnanf' could not be resolved
```

for all instances of `isnan`. Using `std::isnan` and including `float.h` and `math.h` don't solve it. Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Sounds like you may have `WIN32` defined somehow, causing it to use the first version of `isValid()`

Comment: I commented out the WIN32 test and version but that didn't solve it.

Answer (score 1):

1) Try to include `<math.h>`
2) Write your own isnan(x) function

```
bool isnan(x)
{
   if (x==x)
   {
      return false;
   }
   else
   {
      return true;
   }
}
```

3) Could it be a silly naming problem?`isnanl` should probably be defined as `isnan`?
See: [Checking if a double (or float) is NaN in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570669/checking-if-a-double-or-float-is-nan-in-c)

Comment: I've tried including math.h, it doesn't solve the problem either. I'm currently using the x==x hack, but I'd rather use the library function instead of the specification. A similar problem appeared under Windows with both _isnan and _finnite so it would be good to know how to fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same issue. isnan() works on command-line but annoyingly, Eclipse reports it as an error. The problem is due to Eclipse CDT using the gcc compiler little differently. Looking a bit deeper, isnan() seems to be a macro that is translated to __isnan() or some other functions depending on some flags. Maybe these flags differ when you compile from Eclipse.

I fixed it by using function

```
__isnan(double x)
```

which can also be found on math.h, works correctly on cmdline compiler and Eclipse does not complain about it.