# c++ negative square root

Tags: c++, for-loop, sqrt

My goal is to print `***` if the square root is negative. But I can't think of a way to change default `nan` text to `***`

```
for(int i=x1;i<=x2;i++){
   double y = sqrt(pow(i,2)+3*i-500);
    if(y = ?){
        outFile << "***";
    }
```

So, what should I write in the if statement to make it possible? Or maybe there is another way to check if the y is nan then print ***

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking if a double (or float) is nan in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570669/checking-if-a-double-or-float-is-nan-in-c)

Comment: There is no such thing as a negative square root.

Comment: Do not get complex on me @fred

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about checking for a negative *input* to the square root function?

```
for (int i = x1; i <= x2; ++i)
{
    double x = pow(i, 2) + 3*i - 500;
    if (x < 0)
    {
        outFile << "***";
    }
    else
    {
        outFile << sqrt(x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Testing for NaN in C++ is [tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570669/checking-if-a-double-or-float-is-nan-in-c). Just use an `if` statement to avoid evaluating the `sqrt` if its argument is negative.

Answer (score 2):

A nan number isn't equal to anything, even to itself.
You could simple test to see if `if( y != y )`.

Comment: @RnD: This is not 100% reliable, check Alf's answer in the linked duplicate for more details.

Answer (score 0):

> My goal is to print *** if the square root is negative. But I can't think of a way to change default nan text to ***

A square root never is negative. But it may be complex. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number

The idea is to expand the set of numbers into the so called *complex plane*, which contains a special number **i** for which is defined **i² = -1**. This allows us to generalize square roots:

**sqrt(a b) = sqrt(a) sqrt(b)**

So we can break down sqrt(-a) into **sqrt(-1) sqrt(a) = i sqrt(a)**

This allows us to change your program into

```
for(int i=x1;i<=x2;i++){
    double X = pow(i,2)+3*i-500;
    double y = sqrt(abs(x));
    if(X < 0){
        outFile << y << "i";
    } else {
        outFile << y;
    }
}
```