# Swift Negative Square Root

Tags: swift, math, error-handling

It looks like this is true in other languages as well ([see thread on C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053064/c-negative-square-root)), but does anyone know why you can't check the result of a negative square root against the `Double.NaN` or `Double.quietNaN` properties in Swift's `Double` struct?

Here is some code I ran in a Playground:

```
sqrt(-5.0)       // (not a number)
Double.NaN       // (not a number)
Double.quietNaN  // (not a number)

Double.NaN == sqrt(-5.0)       // false
Double.quietNaN == sqrt(-5.0)  // false
```

It seems that the Swift playground is printing `sqrt(-5.0)`, `Double.NaN`, and `Double.quietNaN` with the same error string, but that they have different programmatic representations. I can't figure out why this is happening. Any thoughts?

Comment: I googled "Swift Nan" and found this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24351407/2079103

Comment: By convention, NaN compares false against any other value, including NaN.

Comment: Didn't know that NaN compares false against anything else, good to know. I didn't realize Double conforms to FloatingPointNumber... kind of strange. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether a number is NaN by check its equivalent to itself:

```
if aNumber != aNumber {
  println("This is NaN")
}
```

`NaN` is always not equal to itself.

Or you can use the `isNaN` property of a Double number:

```
let number: Double = 5.0
let nanNumber: Double = Double.NaN

number.isNaN  // false
nanNumber.isNaN  // true
```

*Float* numbers also have a `isNaN` property.

Comment: Do you mean `aNumber != aNumber`?