# How do I detect/trap -1.#IND in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, error-handling, numbers

I have tried all of my normal tricks for detecting odd numbers (NaN, QNaN,etc) and I can't seem to detect -1.#IND.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking if a double (or float) is nan in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570669/checking-if-a-double-or-float-is-nan-in-c)

Comment: Also, Note that answer by @Cheers and hth. - Alf is the correct one in the marked duplicate.

Comment: Thanks - we can close this one then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

http://www.johndcook.com/IEEE_exceptions_in_cpp.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried comparing the number to itself:

```
if ( x != x )
   assert(!"nan");
```

or simply

```
assert(x==x);
```

What are your normal tricks?

Also, odd numbers are 1,3,5,..., as in, the opposite of even. You're talking about NaN's I assume.

Comment: I have tried comparing it to itself...  works for NaN, QNan, and INF... not IND...

Comment: @Luchian - he meant odd as in strange / not normal

Answer (score 0):

```
union _IEEESingle
{
   float Float;
   struct
   {
      unsigned int Frac : 23;
      unsigned int Exp  : 8;
      unsigned int Sign : 1;
   } IEEE;
};    

bool isQnan(float in) 
    { 
       return(reinterpret_cast<_IEEESingle*>(&in)->IEEE.Exp == (1u << 8)-1 && 
          reinterpret_cast<_IEEESingle*>(&in)->IEEE.Frac); 
    }
```