# Calculating angle between a line and a point in 3D

Tags: c++, math, trigonometry, angle

I'm working on a problem in c++ where I need to determine the angle between a line represented as 2 points in 3d (etc, x.y.z coordinates) and a disconnected point. Here are some pictures that might be easier to understand.

[This is in 2D to display it easier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFowu.png)

So what I need help with is finding this angle

[With angle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvUII.png)

I've been searching for several hours to solve this now, and I suspect that I've just missed something obvious. But if anyone can help me with this I will be very greatful:)

Comment: suggest posting the picture directly rather than linking to imgurl

Comment: Have you heard about math.stackexchange.com? That's there you wanna go. Example: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/413482/angle-between-different-rays-3d-line-segments-and-computing-their-angular-rela and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/463415/angle-between-two-3d-lines Here we discuss programming.

Comment: Computational geometry is a gray area between math and programming. Please get off your high horse.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

let say you have A(x<sub>1</sub>,y<sub>1</sub>,z<sub>1</sub>) B(x<sub>2</sub>,y<sub>2</sub>,z<sub>2</sub>) C(x<sub>3</sub>,y<sub>3</sub>,z<sub>3</sub>) and the common point is B. So the equation of the line AB becomes : `(x1-x2)i + (y1-y2)j + (z1-z2)k`  and that for BC it is : `(x2-x3)i + (y2-y3)j + (z2-z3)k`

Cos `theta` = `(AB.BC)/(|AB|*|BC|)`

Here is the code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
#define PI 3.14159265
using namespace std; 
int main()
{
    int x1,x2,x3,y1,y2,y3,z1,z2,z3;
    cout<<"for the first\n";
    cin>>x1>>y1>>z1;
    cout<<"\nfor the second\n";
    cin>>x2>>y2>>z2;
    cout<<"\nfor the third\n";
    cin>>x3>>y3>>z3;
    float dot_product = (x1-x2)*(x2-x3) + (y1-y2)*(y2-y3)+ (z1-z2)*(z2-z3);
    float mod_denom1 = sqrt((x1-x2)*(x1-x2) + (y1-y2)*(y1-y2) + (z1-z2)*(z1-z2));
    float mod_denom2 = sqrt((x2-x3)*(x2-x3) + (y2-y3)*(y2-y3) + (z2-z3)*(z2-z3));
    float cosnum = (dot_product/((mod_denom1)*(mod_denom2)));
    float cos = acos(cosnum)*180/PI;
    cout<< cos;
}
```

Comment: don't define `PI` yourself! It's already in math.h, use `M_PI`

Comment: it would also be better to use intermediate values that are equal to `x1-x2`, `x2-x3`, etc. -- the code you have is very prone to copy-paste errors.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 vectors, first related to line in 3D and other vector connecting end point of the line and a point in 3D.

To calculate angle `theta` between 2 vectors, you can take advantage of the fact that `V1.V2 = |V1| x |V2| x consine(theta)`

Here is code snippet I copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10908012/computing-the-scalar-product-of-two-vectors-in-c), to calculate dot product.

```
#include<numeric>    

int main() { 
    double V1[] = {1, 2, 3}; // vector direction i.e. point P2 - point P1
    double V2[] = {4, 5, 6}; // vector direction i.e. point P3 - point P2

    std::cout << "The scalar product is: " 
              << std::inner_product(begin(V1), end(V1), begin(V2), 0.0);

    // TODO: Get theta

    return 0;
}
```

Once you have the dot product, divide it by magnitudes of 2 vectors and then take inverse consine to get theta.

Comment: idk who's downvoting. Not me. This approach works also.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Law of Cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines#Applications):

```
gamma = acos((asq + bsq - csq) / 2 / sqrt(asq*bsq))
```

where `asq` and `bsq` are the squared distances between the vertex and the other two points, and `csq` is the squared distance between those two points.

[image]

(drawing from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Triangle-with-an-unknown-angle-or-side.svg))

Comment: Why the downvote? This is exactly the approach to use. OP still needs to calculate `asq`, `bsq`, `csq` from the original coordinates, but that's fairly easy.