# How to check a double for a QNAN

Tags: c++, comparison, double

Is there a proper way to check for a QNAN other than

```
double t = <QNAN>;
if(t != t)
{
    //t is QNAN
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking if a double (or float) is nan in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570669/checking-if-a-double-or-float-is-nan-in-c)

Comment: @Vlad I'm looking for a xplatform C++ solution and one that doesn't revolve around NaN==NaN being false.

Comment: C99 has an `isnan()` macro in `math.h`, but `t != t` is actually more portable. Also, it doesn't involve old C header files.

Comment: Can you show us a platform where NaN == NaN is not false? If you can, we can add it to the list of broken platforms.

Answer (score 0):

isnan() is part of C++11.

```
std::isnan(float);
std::isnan(double);
std::isnan(long double);
```

Comment: But, is there anything for us who have yet to move onto C++11?

Comment: isnan() is also in C99 and posix, and Microsoft implements _isnan()