# How to test for -1.#IND (indeterminate) in Lua?

Tags: lua, nan, ieee-754

**Irrelavent justification for the question**:

i'm getting an error calling Lua `format`:

> integer overflow attempting to store -1.#IND

The variable's `type(n)` really *is* a `number`, and i can `format` it as a string (i.e. `%s`), but it's not a number, e.g.:

```
print(string.format("value=%s, type=%s", n, type(n)));
```

for the `NaN` value returns:

> value=-1.#IND, type=number

i want to fix this, but i have no idea who is generating this `NaN` (Lua has no debugger).

So i'm left with having to throw a lot of `asserts` all over the code until i can pin down to the source of this intermittent `NaN` value.

But i can't find any condition that traps it, and Lua doesn't have `isnan(x)`.

**Question**:

How can i test a number for `-1.#IND` in Lua?

**Update**:

i tried:

```
if (n ~= n) then
   print(string.format("NaN: value=%s, type=%s", n, type(n)));
else
   print(string.format("value=%s, type=%s", n, type(n)));
end;
```

and it prints

> value=-1.#IND, number

**Update Two**: Just in case i missed something, my *actual* code is:

```
    if (oldValue ~= oldValue) then
        print(string.format("Is NaN: labelNumber=%d, formatString=\"%s\", oldValue=%s (%s)", labelNumber or 0, formatString or "nil", oldValue or "nil", type(oldValue)));
    else
        print(string.format("Is not NaN: labelNumber=%d, formatString=\"%s\", oldValue=%s (%s)", labelNumber or 0, formatString or "nil", oldValue or "nil", type(oldValue)));
    end;
```

And the faulty value outputs:

> Is not NaN: labelNumber=4, formatString="%d", oldValue=-1.#IND (number)

### Update Three

Still trying to solve this problem, i just noticed the absurdadity of reality:

```
function isnan(x)
   if type(x) ~= "number" then
       return false; --only a number can not be a number
   end;

   ...
end;
```

Comment: what does print(n ~= n) give?

Comment: @Random832 `n ~= n` returns `false` when `n` (`number`) = `-1.#IND`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`n ~= n` may work (with the caveats described in Mud's answer), but a more portable one may be:

`function isnan(n) return tostring(n) == tostring(0/0) end`

Those who are concerned about division by zero (as in Ian's comment; although I haven't seen it in practice) can use an alternative version:

`function isnan(n) return tostring(n) == tostring((-1)^.5) end`

Full function:

```
--local nanString = (tostring((-1) ^ 0.5)); --sqrt(-1) is also NaN. 
--Unfortunately, 
--  tostring((-1)^0.5))       = "-1.#IND"
--  x = tostring((-1)^0.5))   = "0"
--With this bug in LUA we can't use this optimization
local function isnan(x) 
    if (x ~= x) then
        --print(string.format("NaN: %s ~= %s", x, x));
        return true; --only NaNs will have the property of not being equal to themselves
    end;

    --but not all NaN's will have the property of not being equal to themselves

    --only a number can not be a number
    if type(x) ~= "number" then
       return false; 
    end;

    --fails in cultures other than en-US, and sometimes fails in enUS depending on the compiler
--  if tostring(x) == "-1.#IND" then

    --Slower, but works around the three above bugs in LUA
    if tostring(x) == tostring((-1)^0.5) then
        --print("NaN: x = sqrt(-1)");
        return true; 
    end;

    --i really can't help you anymore. 
    --You're just going to have to live with the exception

    return false;
end
```

Comment: It should be noted that `n ~= n` does not always work (as @Mud linked to); nor does it work for me.

Comment: @Ian, right; that's why "tostring(n) == tostring(0/0)" may be a more portable way as I noted. If someone doesn't want the "string" representation to be match, then "type(n) == 'number' and tostring(n) == tostring(0/0)" should do.

Comment: i also have reports of some people getting *"division by zero"* errors, rather than "division by zero" simply returning `+INF` or `-INF`.

Comment: @Ian: that's interesting; do you know under what circumstances? I use 0/0 representation in my serializer (https://github.com/pkulchenko/serpent) and haven't seen any reports about division by zero (although nan numbers seem to be rarely used).

Comment: i haven't been able to figure out why they'll get a division by zero error on a `x = y / z` when `z` is zero. My system raises no error. Nonetheless i had check `if z == 0 then x = 0 else x = y/z end`.

Comment: @Ian, updated the answer to add an alternative solution that should avoid division by zero problem.

Comment: Strangely enough `tostring((-1) ^ 0.5)` is `"-1.#IND"`, but `local s = tostring((-1) ^ 0.5)` has `s = "0"`.

Answer (score 1):

> Lua doesn't have isnan(x).

You can add one to your Lua host or create a module with that function. Just a few lines of code.

> How can i test a number for -1.#IND in Lua?

Well, you know that it's converting NaN in to the string representation `'-1.#IND'`, so you could write:

```
function isnan(n) return tostring(n) == '-1.#IND' end
```

Or, [depending on the platform, compiler, compiler settings, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570669/checking-if-a-double-or-float-is-nan-in-c), this will work:

```
function isnan(n) return n ~= n end
```

Comment: It's safe to say that for the same reason that `n ~= n` doesn't always work, that `tostring(n) == "-1.#IND"` will not always work. Depending on the compiler, platform, or locale, the return of `tostring(n)` can also be `NaN` (at least in enUS). Some other versions of *"NaN"* that you're likely to see are: *非数値*, *NkN*, *μη αριθμός*, *غ ع*, *ᠲᠤᠭᠠᠠ ᠪᠤᠰᠤ*, *ཨང་ཀི་མིན་པ།*, *ꌗꂷꀋꉬ*, *不是一個數字*, *非数字*, *NeuN* and *EdZ*.

Comment: The main objection of the linked question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570669/checking-if-a-double-or-float-is-nan-in-c is a g++ compiler flag called `--fast-math` and similar optimizations in other compilers, which do not apply to Lua as they do not affect the bytecode. Or at least I don't know how they would. So the only reason for `x~=x` not working would be if the FPU itself had a non-IEEE conforming floating point implementation. That would be an interesting find though.

Answer (score 0):

For serializing purposes, this seems to work best for me:

```lua
local function isnan(val)
    if val==1/0 then return "1/0"
    elseif val==-1/0 then return "-1/0"
    elseif val~=val then return "0/0"
    end
end
```

This lets me:

```lua
print(v .. " = " .. isnan(val) or val)
```

The result is then, for example,

```lua
{
  foo = 1/0,
  bar = 0/0,
  bla = -1/0,
}
```