# Defining NaN as 0

Tags: c, nan

Whenever NaN is returned, I would like for the value returned to instead be 0. What is the best way to go about achieving this end?

Comment: Can you explain more of the context you need to do this? It's too open-ended right now.

Comment: relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570669/checking-if-a-double-or-float-is-nan-in-c

Comment: Curious: Wasn't @Pavan solution an acceptable one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this function

```
float zero_nan(float n)
{
  return n == n ? n : 0;
}
```

you can inline the function and wrap any return values you think may be nans.