# How to check the float variable contain Real Numbers or not in c++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, numbers

How to check the float variable contain Real Numbers or not in C++ ?

**ex: -1.#IND000** my value

How to determine whether it is Real numbers or like above numbers .

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570669/checking-if-a-double-or-float-is-nan-in-c] (Checking if a double or float is nan in C++)

Comment: Stephen's link's good - though you have to dig a little: numbers can be +/- infinite as well as NaN: you can use e.g. isfinite() from boost: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/special/fpclass.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are functions like [`std::isnan`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isnan) in header `<cmath>`.

Comment: There is no isnan() function available in current C++ Standard Library now

Comment: @HitMe The *current* C++ standard library is C++11. If your compiler doesn't support C++11 yet, there's `isnan` in `<math.h>` as of C99. If your compiler doesn't even support that, consider upgrading it.

Comment: It's specified in C++11 26.8.3.

Answer (score 2):

converting into bool (explicitly o by mean of whatever logical operator) will give "false" for all values that are not "real" or that are 0, so

```
bool is_number(double d)
{ return d || d==0; }
```

should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

These following returns `true` if it's a number, `false` otherwise:

```
bool test1(double d) { return d == d; }
bool test2(double d) { return d * 0.0 == 0.0; }
```

These's a good discussion on [Checking if a double (or float) is nan in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570669/checking-if-a-double-or-float-is-nan-in-c).

Answer (score 1):

A very simple way..

```
float a=3.9;
long b;
b=a;
if ((float)b==a)
    cout<<"Non-real, i.e. integer";
else
    cout<<"REAL";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use '_isnan' in Visual Studio (it is included in float.h):

```
float T;

T=std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN(); //YOUR CALCS HERE!!

if (_isnan(T)) {
    printf("error\n");
}
```