# Why can't I compile IsNan in C++ Builder

Tags: c++, math, c++builder

I'm using C++ Builder XE and want to check a float value is valid. According to the help, in math.h, there's a call

```
bool IsNan(float value)
```

However, when I try to compile this, it tells me

```
Call to undefined function 'IsNan'
```

Looking in math.h, there's no such thing as isnan (I used a non-case sensitive search)

Am I doing something silly, or what ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2123781/57135

Comment: Basically: there is not consistent support for isnan; it's a macro in C99 (which some c++ compilers will let you use), and I believe it was added into C++11, but I don't know if C++Builder conforms to that yet/will ever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use the Embarcadero inbuilt `IsNan()` function you need to include (for XE4 anyway)

```
#include <System.Math.hpp>
```

If you are using basic XE then you need

```
#include <Math.hpp>
```

The latter also works on XE4 although the help indicates that `System.Math.hpp` is needed.

Comment: `Math.hpp` includes `System.Math.hpp` for backwards compatibility with pre-UnitScopeName code, that is why `Math.hpp` works on XE4 even though `System.Math.hpp` is actually needed.

Answer (score 0):

On the forum "Embarcadero Discussion Forums » C++Builder » C++ Language" Roger Dunk wrote:
std::_isnan()

This solved the error for me ...