# gcc -Ofast - complete list of limitations

Tags: c++, gcc, fast-math

I'm using `-Ofast` gcc option in my program cause latency requirements. I wrote simple test program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

static double quiet_NaN = std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();

int main()
{
    double newValue = 130000; 
    double curValue = quiet_NaN; 
    printf("newValue = %f\n", newValue); 
    printf("curValue = %f\n", curValue); 
    printf("isnan(newValue) = %d\n", isnan(newValue)); 
    printf("isnan(curValue) = %d\n", isnan(curValue)); 
    printf("newValue == curValue %d\n", (newValue == curValue)); 
    printf("newValue != curValue %d\n", (newValue != curValue)); 
}
```

I've tried to run it with default flags and with -Ofast:

```
$ g++ TestPointer.cpp 
$./a.out 
newValue = 130000.000000
curValue = nan
isnan(newValue) = 0
isnan(curValue) = 1
newValue == curValue 0
newValue != curValue 1

$ g++ -Ofast TestPointer.cpp 
$ ./a.out 
newValue = 130000.000000
curValue = nan
isnan(newValue) = 0
isnan(curValue) = 1
newValue == curValue 1
newValue != curValue 0
```

So the result of `!=` and `==` can not be trusted. Does it mean that I should `==` and `!=` only when both values are known to be not nan, otherwise I should test with `isnan` before?

Is it guaranteed that `isnan` works correctly with `-Ofast`?
How correctly `==` and `!=` works for double with `-Ofast`?
Can someone provide complete list of limitations added by `-Ofast`?

Comment: Why are you using -Ofast in the first place? Did you read the doc? It is the same as -O3 -ffast-math, where -ffast-math means you don't care if float/double give wrong results as long as they are fast...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're observing the effects of `-ffast-math`.

From the [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html):

> -Ofast
>
> Disregard strict standards compliance. -Ofast enables all -O3 optimizations. It also
>   enables optimizations that are not valid for all standard-compliant programs. It turns on
>   -ffast-math and the Fortran-specific -fno-protect-parens and -fstack-arrays.

and

> -ffast-math
>
> Sets -fno-math-errno, -funsafe-math-optimizations, 
>   -fno-trapping-math, -ffinite-math-only, -fno-rounding-math, -fno-signaling-nans and fcx-limited-range.

and

> -ffinite-math-only
>
> Allow optimizations for floating-point arithmetic that assume that arguments and
>   results are not NaNs or +-Infs.

There are several gcc bug reports for this marked invalid.

[Problems with -ffast-math and isnan](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=25975)

Additionally, comparison of strict IEEE floating points always results in false.

[Checking if a double (or float) is NaN in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570669/checking-if-a-double-or-float-is-nan-in-c)

This doesn't necessarily apply for `-ffast-math` but it explains what you show.

gcc does not describe a formal standard for how `-ffast-math` floats work so you'll just have to work out the details empirically if you must and not assume consistency between versions of gcc. Better yet, completely avoid the combination of `NaN` and `-ffast-math`.

Comment: can I use `isnan` and `-Ofast`? will it work? Or it is not guaranteed and sometimes I can get true, sometimes false?

Comment: You should avoid the combination of NaN and `-ffast-math` completely but my guess is that `isnan` will behave as expected for an explicitly set NaN. Even if it does though, don't assume it always will.

Comment: do you know how can I set `-Ofast` except `-ffast-math`?

Comment: Check the description of `-Ofast` above. Without `-ffast-math` it's just O3.

Comment: are you sure? Why someone need `-Ofast` then? Why just not using `-O3` and `-ffast-math`? What is the reason to introduce special option to combine just two options?

Comment: The docs are quite clear on what `-Ofast` does. If you're compiling Fortran it does do more than `-ffast-math`. I guess it's there to have an O level means "do everything, even if it isn't quite standards compliant" and at the moment that only includes `-ffast-math` for C++.

Comment: I should mention that (at least in GCC 6+), I observe strange behavior with regards to aliasing with -Ofast that does not occur with -O3 -ffast-math in C. Although this doesn't apply to math per se, it reveals there are more differences than the docs claim.