# How to make C99 math functions available in -std=gnu++98 mode with GCC 4.3?

Tags: c++, gcc, libstdc++

I want to use `isfinite` function in my C++ code.

This function is available in the default `math.h` but not in the default version(-std=gnu++98) of `cmath`.

So if I include `math.h` and make sure `cmath` is not included, then `isfinite` is available.

If any of other header files, like `valarray` includes `cmath`, then `isfinite` is gone.

C++11 in GCC 4.3 is experimental so I don't want to turn it on.

Is there a way to use C99 `math.h` in C++98 code?

I found [this related question on testing NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570669/checking-if-a-double-or-float-is-nan-in-c), and the non-C++11 solutions seems very ugly.

**EDIT**

As is pointed by @old_mountain in the comment, when `cmath` is used, `isfinite` is still available but need to be called by `std::isfinite`, using the `std` namespace.

Comment: Are you getting errors using `cmath` and `std::isfinite` ? Apparently it runs fine with [g++4.3.6](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/fFGmUSXLyMYxmQpx). If you use just `isfinite` (without namespace) you'll get an error

Comment: is boos or `std::tr1` not an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include `<cmath>` and use [`std::isfinite`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isfinite) with `std` namespace.

It should [work fine (g++4.3.6)](http://]http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/fFGmUSXLyMYxmQpx)

Comment: Is that standard compliant? isfinite is marked as C++11 so it is possibly a bug that GCC allow using that without std=c++11 flag

Answer (score 0):

Create the function yourself! According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math) that function is available as part of C++11 standard, so I'm not sure is portable using `std::isfinite` with GCC 4.3.X

**isfinite.cpp**

```
#include <math.h>

bool myIsFinite(float arg){
    return isfinite(arg)!=0;
}


bool myIsFinite(double arg){
    return isfinite(arg)!=0;
}
```

**isfinite.hpp**

```
bool myIsFinite(float arg);
bool myIsFinite(double arg);
```

---

---

If you still want to call a function called "isfinite" (I do not suggest that):

**isfinite.cpp**

```
bool myIsFinite(float arg);
bool myIsFinite(double arg);

bool isfinite(float arg){
    return myIsFinite(arg);
}


bool isfinite(double arg){
    return myIsFinite(arg);
}

#include <math.h>

bool myIsFinite(float arg){
    return isfinite(arg)!=0;
}


bool myIsFinite(double arg){
    return isfinite(arg)!=0;
}
```

**isfinite.hpp**

```
bool isfinite(float arg);
bool isfinite(double arg);
```

**WARNING**

You will not be able to do things like "single translation unit" using this file. So you have to exclude "isfinite.cpp" from any single compilation unit and compile it apart alone.

Comment: I tried something similar. I wrote a `extern "C"` wrapper to a c version and compiled it in C99 mode. I did some research and found out using `.h` C headers in C++ code isn't good practice.

Comment: this is not C, but C++ code. The only downside is that C use a lot of macros that pollute namespace, but as you see the inclusion of  `math.h` is done in a small tiny C++ file wich prevent any namespace pollution to code including `isfinite.hpp`. And as you see I don't used "extern" (wich alter the name mangling, wich could be another issue to deal with, but again I resolved it by using C++ and hiding behind it all C code ;) )