# Double Comparison with itself

Tags: c++

I have a code piece that I'm analysing but I don't understand this lines:

```
double level = 0;

...

if (!(level == level) && !(level < level) && !(level > level))
    exit(0);
```

I think it is about double comparison subject. Any idea what it is?

Comment: See NAN (Not A Number) which would make this expression return true.

Comment: Who has written this?

Comment: My first thought would be that they're trying to see if `level` is NaN. I assume there is some intervening code that you've elided that changes the value of `level`? Where did you get this code? What does it do?

Comment: The test with `==` tests for NaN. The tests using `<` and `>` seem pointless.

Comment: [Related: Answer to "Checking if a double (or float) is NaN in C++"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/570694/96780)

Comment: @CodyGray Yes, it calculates power of the values and accumulate in it.   for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    level += values[i] * values[i];

Comment: @i486 I don't know who wrote it but is it important?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a rather over-engineered test for *not a number* (NaN).

NaN is a special floating point value. (Not all floating point types have it but the most common one - IEEE754 - does.)

It's defined to compare not equal to all other numbers, including itself.

It's also defined to be not greater than or not less than any other number, including itself. (Although this subsequent test is superfluous).

From C++11, you can use `std::isnan(level)` instead. Before then, my favourite way of testing was to use the considerably simpler expression `level != level`.