# Filter OpenCV Mat for NAN values

Tags: c++, opencv, nan, mat

Is there a direct way to create a mask where values in a `cv::Mat_<double>` are compared against NAN?

```
cv::Mat_<real> mat = ...
cv::Mat_<uchar> mask = (mat == NAN);
```

does not work because `f == NAN` is always false, even if `f` was assigned `NAN`. And there seems to be no overload of `isnan()` for matrices.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As noted by user pSoLT, if you want to determine which values are `NaN`, simply compare the matrix with itself.  For those elements that are not equal, those would be considered as `NaN` [by the standard definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570669/checking-if-a-double-or-float-is-nan-in-c).  You can create a new mask using that logic:

```
cv::Mat mask = cv::Mat(mat != mat);
```

`mat` here would be a matrix that contains `NaN` values and `mask` will be a `CV_8UC1` (i.e. `uchar`) type matrix with each element being `0xFF` if a value is `NaN` and `0x00` otherwise.

This post on OpenCV forums may also help: http://answers.opencv.org/question/2221/create-a-mask-for-nan-cells/

---

## Edit (as of April 23, 2020)

As mentioned in the comments as well as one of the answers in this post, the above Boolean expression is buggy and can result in inconsistent behaviour.  This is due to certain optimisation decisions that OpenCV makes.  Please see this Github issue: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/16465

The solution to this is to use [`cv::patchNaNs()`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.3.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga62286befb7cde3568ff8c7d14d5079da) to address this problem, which converts values that are `NaN` to a specific number.

To replicate creating the mask in the question, note that `patchNaNs` performs an in-place replacement of the values, so you would have to make two copies of the image, use the `patchNaNs` to set the `NaN` values to a distinct value per image then check to see the occurrence of both values at the same locations at the same time.  In other words:

```
cv::Mat mat1 = mat.clone();
cv::Mat mat2 = mat.clone();
cv::patchNaNs(mat1, 128);
cv::patchNaNs(mat2, 200);
cv::Mat mask = mat1 == 128 & mat2 == 200;
```

`mask` will give you the results as expected in the original version of this answer.

Comment: There is a bug in OpenCV which causes this operation to result in inconsistent behaviour. See https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/16465

Comment: Definitely aware of this @AndrewMarshall. patchNANs was introduced for this very reason. There's an answer already here for that but I'll update mine for closure. I just haven't had the time.... Given what's currently going on right now!

Answer (score 3):

I am posting this answer to be a reference for those who may be searching for how to filter out the `nan`'s from a matrix.

Although it may not be the precise answer to your question, if you want to filter out those `nan` indices, there is a quick and easy way to do it.

In my case, I had a `zero by zero division` which ended up `nan`s in my `float` matrix. To set those `nan`'s to another value (in my case `0`), the following method can be used:

```
cv::patchNaNs(mat, 0.0);
```

This method finds and replaces the `nan` indices with the given value.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test value for `NaN` simply compare it with itself. According to standard `NaN` is not equal to any other number, including itself `(fValue != fValue)` should be true for NaN.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [github issue](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/16465), a workaround is to use `255 - (mat == mat)` instead of  `mat != mat` (this should work in general, but is a bug currently).
[rayryeng's double-patch approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41759433/7128154) is more robust, but brings a significant performance drawback.

**Here a minimal working example:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

cv::Mat1b is_nan(cv::Mat mat)
{
    return 255 - (mat == mat);
}


int main()
{
    cv::Mat mat(5, 7, CV_32FC1);
    cv::randu(mat, cv::Scalar(-1), cv::Scalar(1));
    mat.at<float>(0,0) = std::nan("");
    mat.at<float>(4,5) = std::nan("");
    
    std::cout << mat << std::endl;
    std::cout << is_nan(mat) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**output**

```
[nan, -0.60148162, -0.19788112, 0.62877017, -0.12573405, -0.5024206, 0.54621011;
 0.52418745, -0.38441104, 0.40486339, -0.043105587, 0.58438003, -0.82831377, -0.8498795;
 -0.67315322, -0.40044156, 0.81130785, 0.41937166, -0.70057499, 0.53087986, -0.75143719;
 -0.9925428, 0.10302717, 0.99639863, -0.68201572, -0.6776439, -0.92362136, -0.14827734;
 0.69225526, 0.77520895, -0.47057521, -0.4584339, 0.9053328, nan, 0.62043273]
[255,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0;
   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0;
   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0;
   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0;
   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 255,   0]
```

Comment: I would expect so, but did not check. Is there any specific reason you want to go a special way in a buggy environment?

Comment: `~` meant just for legibility. And no, I am not happy about this inconsistent "optimization", OpenCV should use `-ffast-math` or some preprocessor macro to enable it explicitly.

Comment: I completely agree. At least the missing NAN support of opencv should be mentioned more explicitly (I read it once, but don't remember where). There are a bunsh of other functions which do not work with NANs either. For Instance: `GaussianBlur` or `minMaxLoc`