# how to use AtomiccmpExchange with double?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have a double value that I need to access to inside a backgroundThread. I would like to use somethink like `AtomiccmpExchange` but seam to not work with double. is their any other equivalent that I can use with double ? I would like to avoid to use `Tmonitor.enter` / `Tmonitor.exit` as I need something the most fast as possible. I m under android/ios so under firemonkey

Comment: `PUInt64(@dOld)^ := AtomicCmpExchange(PUInt64(@d)^,PUInt64(@dNew)^,PUint64(@dComp)^);` Align variables properly.

Comment: Beware also that with floating point you can have a <> a and also 0 = -0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could type cast the `double` values into `UInt64` values:

```
PUInt64(@dOld)^ := AtomicCmpExchange(PUInt64(@d)^,PUInt64(@dNew)^,PUInt64(@dCom‌​p)^);
```

Note that you need to align the variables properly, according to platforms specifications.

---

As @David pointed out, comparing `double`values is not the same as comparing `UInt64` values. There are some specific double values that will behave out of the ordinary:

- A `NaN` is normally (as specified in [IEEE-754](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1573715/576719)) detected by comparing a value by itself.

  ```
  IsNaN := d <> d;
  ```

  *footnote: Delphi default exception handler is triggered in the event of comparing a NaN, but other compilers may behave differently. In Delphi there is an `IsNaN()` function to use instead.*
- Likewise the value zero could be both positive and negative, for a [special meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Special_values). Comparing double `0` with double `-0` will return true, but comparing the memory footprint will return false.

Comment: What is `d <> d`? Could you elaborate that, please? It's some kind of compiler _magic_ or so? I'm aware of `IsNan` function, but that does internally something else than you present.

Comment: @Victoria, [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) specifies that a floating point variable with a value of NaN gives false when compared for equality. (Details in the link). This is often used in systems where a sensor can give NaN's as a result of certain conditions. Then you have to test for NaN before proceeding with calculations.

Comment: Thank you, but why is `IsNan` function in Delphi implemented in a different way?

Comment: @Victoria, I'm aware that the Delphi's math unit has another way of testing (at bit level). I don't know why at the moment, but many industri c compilers operate as described. A quiet NaN is not supposed to signal an exception when loaded into the FPU, but that is what will happen in Delphi. More on the subject [NaN](http://www.wow.com/wiki/NaN). Feel free to ask a question about this subject here at SO. A similar question about C++ is here :https://stackoverflow.com/a/570694/576719

Comment: Well, so long I'm not a high reputation user asking how is something implemented in Delphi in a certain way, it could be a bad received question (which I don't care) which might be finally deleted by _haters_ (which is wasting of helper's time). I know assembler very well just for a subset of a few microcontrollers, not much about assembler of _PC_ processors. You seem to be keen about it, hence I asked :)

Comment: Don't be afraid of asking. The subject has been touched, but I have never seen a straight Delphi question. My guess is that the exception mask is set to trigger all NaN's for convenience, and since there is a function supplied to test for NaN's, all was fine. Finally the SO link I was looking for: [What is the rationale for all comparisons returning false for IEEE754 NaN values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1565164/576719).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use of **System.SyncObjs.TInterlocked** class methods will be better?