# OpenCL - double is neither <= 300 or >= 200? C++

Tags: c++, opencl

```
double test = 0.0;
.... some code
char qwe = ...
.. some code
test += qwe;
if (test >= 200 || test <= 300) {
   test = 7.0;
}
// For some reason, test seems to equal 0?
```

Why does `(test >= 200 || test <= 300)` == false?

It's very strange behaviour.

And when I print the output, it's 0?

Comment: Have you tried to change the variable test to an int? Or change the comparison >= 200.0 || <= 300.0?

Comment: What is the test supposed to do? And what does it have to do with OpenCL? Perhaps if you showed your *real* code...

Comment: You need to provide a verifiable sample!

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe *mumble mumble* coffee *mumble* brain *mumble mumble*.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: Not necessary. There is only one possibility, and can be quite hard to construct a demo case for that (if you don't know the cause!)

Comment: @Bathsheba That would be true under quite a few assumptions. Not true under others. E.g. test in the condition is not the same `test` as `test=0.0`.

Comment: @Bathsheba the if() may also get optimized out as a consequence of UB (invoked somewhere in the '...'; for example, his real code could miss to initialize test)

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: I still think the OP has done their best in this particular case. It's really bewildering on a first encounter.

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes: Yes, you're technically correct on that point, although I've never observed it.

Comment: @Bathsheba [gcc is famous for doing so](https://godbolt.org/g/79MKsY) :)

Answer (score 6):

Notwithstanding any undefined behaviour in your program, `(test >= 200 || test <= 300) == false` if, and only if, `test` is `NaN`. You can get a `NaN` (not a number) by some numerical error, such as `0.0 / 0.0` or by calling `sqrt` with a negative input.

Use `std::isnan(test)` to check for sure.

Comment: May be, it's worth to mention that a NaN value has also another surprising behavior: It's the only value for which `f != f` is true. Because I wasn't sure about it I googled and even found this answer [SO: Checking if a double (or float) is NaN in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/570694/7478597) ...which is as short and precise as yours.

Comment: @Scheff: Yes that does work, but compilers are increasingly optimising out that technique.

Comment: Just to add: As the question mentions OpenCL in both title and tags, this might be in OpenCL kernel code. In that case, the function for testing for NaN is `isnan()`, as OpenCL doesn't have namespaces and a different set of built-in functions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Bathsheba, it was because of it being NaN. - OP

Comment: @JamesSin: Glad to be of help. You certainly will never forget the possibility. It's really vexing on first encounter isn't it?

Comment: @Bathsheba Yup :D