# C++ advice on exception handling

Tags: c++, exception

As I am very new to exceptions, I am having some trouble with the below memory exception code. Basically, I would need to calculate and show sum of 10 positive inputs. During the input, my program should use exception mechanism to display a message that it doesn't allow **negative numbers / not-a-numbers (NaN)** if so is the input and then exit the program. I am told to use **std::cin.fail()** to detect whether the value entered fits the variable type(but I am not sure how to implement it). Would appreciate your help thanks!

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int number;
    int a=-2;
try {

    for(int i=0; i<10;i++) {
    std::cin>>number;

    }
}
catch (...) {

    number==-number?
      std::cout << "Its negative"<<std::endl; 

    number==a? 
      std::cout << "Its NaN"<<std::endl; 
    }
}
```

Comment: the stream itself can be tested as a boolean to see if a read failed. eg: `if (std::cin>>number) { test number for negative/NaN and throw exception if true } else { didn't get a number at all. Throw exception }`

Comment: Hi @user4581301, how do I test for NaN? Thanks for ur input.

Comment: If your compiler is reasonably recent (Supports C++11), you can use the aptly named [`isnan`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isnan). If not, [it gets ugly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570669/checking-if-a-double-or-float-is-nan-in-c).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say "10 positive inputs", but you have `int number;`. If your `number` is going to be an integer, then it can't take fractions like `33.44` for instance, and it also can't be `NaN` (so you wouldn't need to check for that). If you want to allow fractions, do `double number` instead. That aside, the check could look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        std::cin >> number;
        if (std::cin.fail()) {
            std::cin.clear();
            std::string input;
            std::cin >> input;
            std::cout << "input failed! Invalid input: " << input << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
```

After every inputted number, you do the `std::cin.fail()` check. If it failed, you can just return. In this example, I also made it print the invalid input. For that you need to call `std::cin.clear();` to reset that error flag, and then you can put that invalid input into an `std::string` (which should work, unlike with the `number`). You need to include `<string>` for that. If you don't need to print anything, you can just `return` and forget about the clearing, the string and the output. Also, in this example, since the mess made by the invalid input is neatly cleaned up, you could take more (valid) inputs again if you don't `return` instead.

Next, checking for negative numbers:

```
if (number < 0) {
    std::cout << "Error: Negative number!" << std::endl;
    return -1;
}
```

Finally, the `NaN` check (for `double`):

```
if (isnan(number)) {
    std::cout << "Error: number is NaN!" << std::endl;
    return -1;
}
```

You need to include `<math.h>` for the `isnan`.

Putting it all together, it could look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> // std::istream >> std::string
#include <math.h> // isnan

int main() {
    double number;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        std::cin >> number;
        if (std::cin.fail()) {
            std::cin.clear();
            std::string input;
            std::cin >> input;
            std::cout << "input failed! Invalid input: " << input << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
        if (number < 0) {
            std::cout << "Error: Negative number!" << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
        if (isnan(number)) {
            std::cout << "Error: number is NaN!" << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```