# How remove NAN from C++ vector?

Tags: c++, nan

I have

```
std::vector<double>x={1,2,NAN,3, NAN, 4}
```

when I try `x.erase(remove(x.begin(), x.end(), NAN), x.end()`, I still see `NAN` as

```
for (auto i:x)
    std::cout<<i<<" ";
```

gives

```
1 2 -nan(ind) 3 -nan(ind) 4
```

how can I remove the NANs so the output is below?

```
1 2 3 4
```

EDIT: `x` is a vector of doubles, not ints

Comment: NAN does not equal NAN.  Have to check for is_nan... not sure if that's a supplied predicate, or if you have to make your own.

Comment: @Eljay `isnan` is in `<cmath>`

Comment: Just fix your real code.  Trying to remove an inconvenient truth only produces nonsense results that makes the real problem undiagnosable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't work, since NAN doesn't equal NAN (this is not specified by C++ standard, but in IEEE 754 standard, which your system probably conforms to). `std::remove`, uses equality as the condition to choose elements for removal.

Instead of `std::remove`, you need to use `std::remove_if` with a predicate using `std::isnan`.

Answer (score 8):

In the weird, wild world of IEEE 754 floating point, NaN != NaN. In other words, two not-a-number values do *not* compare as equal to each other. So, you cannot simply let `std::remove` do an equality test.

You need to supply your own predicate that calls a function to determine whether or not a floating-point value is NaN. If you're targeting C++11 or later, the standard library provides such a function: `std::isnan`. (If not, [the situation is a bit more complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570669/checking-if-a-double-or-float-is-nan-in-c).)

Putting it all together, then, the correct code would look like this:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    std::vector<double> x = {
                              1,
                              2,
                              std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN(),
                              3,
                              std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN(),
                              4
                            };

    std::cout << "Before removing: ";
    for (auto i : x)
    {
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    x.erase(std::remove_if(std::begin(x),
                           std::end(x),
                           [](const auto& value) { return std::isnan(value); }),
            std::end(x));

    std::cout << "After removing: ";
    for (auto i : x)
    {
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In case it got lost in all the demo code, the relevant part is just:

```
x.erase(std::remove_if(std::begin(x),
                       std::end(x),
                       [](const auto& value) { return std::isnan(value); }),
        std::end(x));
```

where I am passing a lambda to `std::remove_if` as a unary predicate. It calls `std::isnan`, passing in the value to check, and it returns the result, which is a Boolean indicating whether or not the value is not-a-number. If the predicate returns true, `std::remove_if` does the removal; otherwise, it doesn't.

Note that the logic in floating-point world is typically that NaN values are *infectious*. In other words, any operation involving a NaN will return NaN as a result. So, it strikes me as a bit odd that you're trying to remove all NaN values. Be careful not to just shove them under the rug as if they weren't there.